# ASP.NET MVC4 Twitter Bootstrap Radio Button Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using Bootstrap V3 and MVC4.

I am having issues accessing and formatting data using bootstrap defined radio buttons.

When I declare my radio buttons using the following - Specifically `data-toggle="buttons"`:

```
       <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" style="padding-bottom:10px">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.searchType, "radiobutton1") RadioButton 1
    </label>


    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.searchType, "radiobutton2") RadioButton2
    </label>
 </div>
```

The result is:

[image: Radiobuttons]

Everything looks perfect. When I select a button, it gets pressed until I select the other.

However, when I submit the form, the value is not passed through to the controller. It is null. I have a strongly typed view that gets values from a textbox and the radio buttons on the page.

---

When I define my radio buttons using the following - Specifically `data-toggle="buttons-radio"`:

```
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio" style="padding-bottom:10px">

        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.searchType, "radiobutton1") RadioButton 1
        </label>


        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.searchType, "radiobutton2") RadioButton2
        </label>
</div>
```

My result is

[image: Radiobuttons]

This is not how I want my buttons. The little circles are visible. Not to mention, once I select one of the buttons there is no turning back. I am forced to keep that one, I cannot select the other option.

The one good thing about this option is that I am able to pass in the value that is selected to the controller. When the form is submitted, I am able to see that the value of searchType in my model object is either Radiobutton1 or Radiobutton2.

---

And for those wondering, this is what my model looks like. It has a spot for searchType and searchString.

```
public class SearchForm
{

    public string searchString{ get; set; }

    public string searchType { get; set; }
}
```

---

What I am asking is how do I combine the 2 results?

One looks perfect but doesn't pass data, the other looks bad and passes in the date.

I have narrowed it down to the `data-toggle` property being set to either `Buttons` or `Buttons-Radio`.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this myself but is the searchType a string on your model? If the value of the radio button and the property of the model don't match it won't get converted properly when it gets submitted

Comment: Yes sir it was. Did it appear to work correctly for you?

I kind of have a "hotfix" for now. As I just posted as an answer.

Comment: Yes it did work for me. The other thing I noticed in your HTML you posted, you didn't close the div tag of your btn-group

Comment: Ah, that was just from copying and pasting over. I really would like it to work via my first choice using `data-toggle="buttons"`. This is the way it should work.

It is as if it does not like the radio buttons wrapped in a label tag. Its quite frustrating knowing its working for you but not for me. I have updated my question with my simple model.

Comment: One other question as I noticed this while working through this. In the first example do your buttons toggle correctly? I initially forgot to include bootstrap.js and found that without it my radio buttons were not being set as checked.

Comment: Yes. They toggle perfectly. Just no searchType value is being brought in to the controller when the form is submitted. Even though I have `...model=>searchType...`

Comment: btw... Intellisense even picks up `model => model.searchType`. I have tried it in multiple browsers. Either way, it is coming up as null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually all you need to do is add a *name* attribute to each radio button and set it to the model item you want. Then asp.net MVC does its voodoo magic and connects the bits together.
In your case something like the code below should work:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" style="padding-bottom:10px">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.searchType, "radiobutton1", new {name="searchType"}) RadioButton 1
    </label>

    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.searchType, "radiobutton2", new {name="searchType"}) RadioButton2
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: WOW! This solution is sooooo simple and elegant!

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to resolve my own issue however I had to take a different approach. However I will not accept this answer as it does not toggle as it is supposed to. The button stays selected until it is out of focus.

Instead of using `@Html.RadioButtonFor(...)` I went back and I used buttons as my two radio options.

Since when those buttons are clicked, there is no action being taken I had to create a hidden input field, and use javascript to update its value whenever a "radio button" was clicked.

All in all here was my form code:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.searchType)
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button type="button" id="radiobutton1" data-toggle="button" name="search" value="Radiobutton1" class="btn btn-primary">Radiobutton1</button>
    <button type="button" id="radiobutton2" data-toggle="button" name="search" value="radiobutton2" class="btn btn-primary">Radiobutton2</button>
</div>

<script>
    var buttons= ['radiobutton1', 'radiobutton2'];
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById(buttons[i]).addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementByID('searchType') = this.value;
                });
            }
</script>
```

---

**EDIT:**

I have solved the entire issue now.

I have removed my old Javascript with this jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#searchDiv :button").click(function () {
            $("#searchDiv :button").removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');

            $("#searchType").val($(this).attr("value"))
        });
    });
</script>
```

Buttons now toggle correctly. And the value is passed to the hidden field.

This seems to be a little more complicated than it needed to be, but its all good.